# Select2 Widget & Pjax Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, jquery-select2, pjax

I'm trying to add multiple [Select2](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) widgets dynamically in the [TabularForm](https://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form) using Pjax (build-in Ajax component in Yii2). For some reason the Select2 input is rendering on the wrong place at the top of the view (see **gif1** below). As I understood, this issue is related specifically to the Select2 widget as everthing is working fine if I use some default component e.g. Html::a (see **gif2** below).

**gif1**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gUJu.gif

**gif2**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wojwB.gif

How I can get rid of that strange behaviour with the Select2 widget? Thanks is advance!

**Controller:**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
// ...
    public function actionCreate()
    {   
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) { 
            // some logic here ...
            return $this->renderAjax('object/create', [
                // ...
            ]);
        }
    }
// ...

}
```

**View:**

```
// ...
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\select2\Select2Asset;

Select2Asset::register($this);

// a bunch of html code

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'product-add']); ?>
    $form1 = ActiveForm::begin();
    $attribs = [
        'name' => [
         'type' => TabularForm::INPUT_RAW,
          'value' => function($productModel) { 
               return Select2::widget([
                   'name' => 'state_10',
                   'data' => ['1' => '1', '2' => '2'],
                   'pjaxContainerId' => 'product-add',
                   'options' => [
                       'placeholder' => $productModel->tmpId,
                       'multiple' => true
                   ],
               ]);
               //return Html::a('product ' . $productModel->tmpId); <- works fine if I use this piece of code
           },
    ],

    // ...

    Html::a("Add", ['profile/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])

    // ...
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>

// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some closer examination I found the solution. For those who will also face the same issue, you need to initialize your widget (Select2 in my case) before the pjax response, e.g. in your **Controller:**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
// ...
    public function actionCreate()
    {   
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) { 
            // some logic here ...

            // initialize the widget with an appropriate id
            $this->view->registerJs("$({$product->tmpId}).select2();"); 

            return $this->renderAjax('object/create', [
                // ...
            ]);
        }
    }
// ...

}
```

And somewhere in your **View:**

```
Select2::widget([
    'id' => $productModel->tmpId, // set your unique id here
    'name' => $productModel->tmpId,
    'data' => ['1' => '1', '2' => '2'],
    // ...
]);
```